# Symfony access control by roles

Tags: symfony, security, fosuserbundle

I have `FOSUserBundle` and I want to do a simple access list path that if an user is not logged it will send to login page and if is not `ROLE_ADMIN` o other he can't go to `/admin` page .

I write this in my `security.yml`:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

but now all user logged can go to `/admin page`...

I don't understand my wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change

```
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

to

```
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Answer (score 4):

Rules are parsed in the order they're written so,

```
- { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

will grant access to all areas under `/` if user is authenticated

You need to switch last two rules and all will surely work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
- { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```